# Regex substitutions

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to use the `map` function in Perl to replace part of an array of strings with a letter `C`, but I can't figure out the regex to do so. (I have to use `map`, no option to not use it.) Perl is returning `1` for each part of the array rather than the correct string but with `C` instead of the numbers.

Basically, I have the below array in Perl, and I need to change the numerical value to `C`. I need to use `map` to do so, and I'm not sure how to go about it. I tried `@GradeC = map(s/7[2-9]/C/, @GradeC);`, as my Google-fu showed that that could be how to find/replace using regex, but that doesn't work. Full disclosure: this is homework, but I am allowed to use Stack Overflow for help.

```
@GradeC = ("Name: Shemp  Grade: 79",
           "Name: Curly  Grade: 75",  
           "Name: Larry  Grade: 72");


# map statement

print join("\n", @GradeC);
```

Comment: For goodness sake stop using `join` for your output. If that, and the variable names with capitals, are your tutors idea then ***drop out*** immediately. The proper way is `print "$_\n" for @grade_c`.

Comment: I actually got the `join` idea from another Stack Overflow question, not from him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Always `use strict;`.
- Always `use warnings;`
- While you're at it, `use feature qw(say);` and you get to use the `say` statement.

Map takes the elements in the array, sets each one to `$_` and then runs the command against it. It also *aliases* each instant of `$_` with the actual value in the array, so you don't have to do anything.

I'm using `s/7\d/C/` which replaces each instant of 7 followed by a digit with the letter C.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

my @grade_c = (
    "Name: Shemp  Grade: 79",
    "Name: Curly  Grade: 75",  
    "Name: Larry  Grade: 72"
);


map { s/7\d/C/ } @grade_c;
say join "\n", @grade_c;
```

Runs:

```
Name: Shemp  Grade: C
Name: Curly  Grade: C
Name: Larry  Grade: C
```

Comment: That's just a wasteful version of `s/7\d/C/ for @grade_c;`

Comment: The OP wants to use the `map` statement in Perl to do this. The OP even said: _I have to use map, no option to not use it._

Comment: I don't think `use feature qw(say)` is appropriate in production code. It is really a debugging tool.

Comment: @Borodin `say` is not a debugging tool — it helps make the code cleaner. Also, `use strict; use feature qw(say);` can be replaced with `use v5.1x;` which is shorter, dies on perls older than 5.1x and also enables all features present in Perl 5.1x.

Comment: @ikegami: What you appear not to know is that the OP said in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259139) just a few minutes ago that he is asking for help with homework. In such a situation, "I have to use map" means ***"I have to use map"***

Comment: @ikegami: Regarding `say`, I think we will have to disagree. `say` is `print $_, $\` with `$\` defaulted. That isn't in the spirit of Perl as a language.

Comment: @ikegami: I think that would leave most students lost, but whatever. I'm not resolute about it

Comment: `say join "\n", @foo;` vs. `print join "\n", @foo . \n;` 'Nuff said.

Comment: 1) `say` is not a debugging tool. 2) Using `say` is completely appropriate for production code. 3) Using `say` is not unperlish. 4) `say`'s implementation is not important.  5) That he's trying to learn is all the more reason to tell the OP he shouldn't use `map { s/7\d/C/ } @grade_c;`. 6) I'd actually use `say for @foo;` instead of `print "$_\n" for @foo;` or `print map "$_\n", @foo`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be edit your existing structure, than just use a for.

```
for (@GradeC) {
    s/7[2-9]/C/;
}
```

If you really want a new array, then don't forget to return your value after the substitution.  Also, as ikegami pointed out, you don't want to perform on `$_` directly as that will edit your original array, so instead use a temporarily var.

```
my @newGrades = map { my $g = $_; $g =~ s/7[2-9]/C/; $g } @GradeC;
```

Comment: I unfortunately have to use `map` somehow in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This *"allowed to use any and all resources available"* business is ridiculous.

This

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @grade_c = (
  'Name: Shemp  Grade: 79',
  'Name: Curly  Grade: 75',  
  'Name: Larry  Grade: 72',
);


print "$_\n" for map s/grade\s*:\s*\K\d+/C/r, @grade_c;
```

**output**

```
Name: Shemp  Grade: C
Name: Curly  Grade: C
Name: Larry  Grade: C
```

And I am sure you have learned nothing.

Comment: I actually make a point of trying to understand what's going on in these answers; I don't just copy-paste and move on. I use Stack Overflow as a last-ditch attempt rather than my go-to resource. But I do understand your point.

Comment: @Vaindil: Then you would learn a lot more if you asked *specifically* for minimal assistance with your best effort at a solution. In real life I would code this answer.